# Fetching index mail from dovecot

Tags: email, jakarta-mail, thunderbird, dovecot, maildir

I am creating my own client end for my email and i am using Java mail API. I am retrieving messages from dovecot and able to send also through Postfix. But I am not able to retrieve proper index messages as Thunderbird does or any other mail client does.

Please help me with proper explanation.

Comment: Please include a minimum reproducible example and a clear description of what IS happening.

Comment: What's an "index message"?

Comment: I am sorry for my ignorance. I am trying to fetch a mail using java mail which is doing fine but the problem is i am not able to show the related message. The concept of showing the related message is know as  message threading.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what you are trying to accomplish in more detail. Are you able to fetch a message? Are you able to figure out which messages belong to a thread? Can you show us your code for this and trim it down to just the thing which isn't doing what you hope?

Comment: What's the relation between your (apparently ad-hoc) term "index message" and the link to [Wikipedia's article on *Conversation threading*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversation_threading) which you posted but then deleted?

Comment: Thank you Tripee for your reply. For your first question Yes i am able to fetch the messages but i am not able to figure out which message belong to which thread.